# Long Touch handling in Android

Tags: android

I want to open dialog activity  on ***long touch*** of current activity.
I have accomplished it on simple touch event but i want to perform the same on long touch so that if user is touched the screen by mistake it will not affect on app.
How to acieve it?

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Did you try `View.setOnLongClickListener()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't touch an activity but a view that is shown by your activity. You can set a `View.OnLongClickListener` with the `setOnLongClickListener` method.

Comment: 'RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        mainLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //The Action you want to perform
             Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
       startActivity(loginIntent);
       return true;
            }
        });' This shows error in Intent and i can't move to next activity.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to open dialog activity on long touch of current activity.

You can not set the event on click of an Activity you can set the event on the Particular layout or a view(the root layout is better if you want to set it for whole activity).

you can set event on LongClick on view or layout by using following line.

```
  yourViewOrLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //The Action you want to perform
            return false;
        }
    });
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
  rl.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {    
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Long Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false; // do false here
        }
    });
```

**EDIT :**

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(ypurActivity.this, Login.class);
```

Comment: 'code' RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        mainLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //The Action you want to perform
             Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
       startActivity(loginIntent);
       return true;
            }
        }); is not working.

Comment: @PrasadM try to do this `return false;` instead of `return true;`.

Comment: I got error in Intent. It will not accept Intent(this, Login.class).

Comment: do this `Intent(yourActivity.this, Login.class)`. that will solve your problem

Comment: I made mistake somewhere else in code.Now it's working good. Thank you for quick response.